# List of lists of single integer lists to list of lists of single integers

Tags: python, list

I have the following code and I would like it to become a list of lists of integers. Currently it is a list of lists of single-integer lists.

```
 timecolumn = [
     [[19310]]
     [[19310], [19460]],
     [[19310], [19460], [19800]],
     [[19310], [19460], [19800], [20260]],
     [[19310], [19460], [19800], [20260], [20880]],
     [[19310], [19460], [19800], [20260], [20880], [21190]],
     [[19460]],
     [[19460], [19800]],
     [[19460], [19800], [20260]],
     [[19460], [19800], [20260], [20880]],
     [[19460], [19800], [20260], [20880], [21190]],
     [[19800]],
     [[19800], [20260]],
     [[19800], [20260], [20880]],
     [[19800], [20260], [20880], [21190]],
     [[20260]],
     [[20260], [20880]],
     [[20260], [20880], [21190]],
     [[20880]],
     [[20880], [21190]],
     [[21190]]
]
```

I was trying something like this, but I am sure there is a much easier way:

```
for row in timecolumn:
    if len(row) > 1:
        n = len(row)
        l = []
        count = 0
        for b in row:
            if count != n:
                l.append(b)
                count = count + 1

        diffcolumn.append(l)
```

I want it to be a list of list of single integers (not a list of list of single integer lists).

Comment: How did you end up with this format in the first place? Maybe there is a better way to extract whatever data you are fetching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way would be using `map` with `sum` function:

```
timecolumn = list(map(lambda elem: sum(elem,[]), timecolumn))
print(timecolumn)
```

Result:

```
[[19310], [19310, 19460], [19310, 19460, 19800], [19310, 19460, 19800, 20260], [19310, 19460, 19800, 20260, 20880], [19310, 19460, 19800, 20260, 20880, 21190], [19460], [19460, 19800], [19460, 19800, 20260], [19460, 19800, 20260, 20880], [19460, 19800, 20260, 20880, 21190], [19800], [19800, 20260], [19800, 20260, 20880], [19800, 20260, 20880, 21190], [20260], [20260, 20880], [20260, 20880, 21190], [20880], [20880, 21190], [21190]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Something simple like this should work

```
outer = [[item[0] for item in inner] for inner in timecolumn]
```

Provided inner lists only contains one element

Example:

```
timecolumn = [[[19310]],
    [[19310], [19460]],
    [[19310], [19460], [19800]],
    [[19310], [19460], [19800], [20260]],
    [[19310], [19460], [19800], [20260], [20880]],
    [[19310], [19460], [19800], [20260], [20880], [21190]],
    [[19460]],
    [[19460], [19800]],
    [[19460], [19800], [20260]],
    [[19460], [19800], [20260], [20880]],
    [[19460], [19800], [20260], [20880], [21190]],
    [[19800]],
    [[19800], [20260]],
    [[19800], [20260], [20880]],
    [[19800], [20260], [20880], [21190]],
    [[20260]],
    [[20260], [20880]],
    [[20260], [20880], [21190]],
    [[20880]],
    [[20880], [21190]],
    [[21190]]
]

outer = [[item[0] for item in inner] for inner in timecolumn]
```

Output:

```
$ python -i timecolumn.py 
>>> outer
[[19310], [19310, 19460], [19310, 19460, 19800], [19310, 19460, 19800, 20260], [19310, 19460, 19800, 20260, 20880], [19310, 19460, 19800, 20260, 20880, 21190], [19460], [19460, 19800], [19460, 19800, 20260], [19460, 19800, 20260, 20880], [19460, 19800, 20260, 20880, 21190], [19800], [19800, 20260], [19800, 20260, 20880], [19800, 20260, 20880, 21190], [20260], [20260, 20880], [20260, 20880, 21190], [20880], [20880, 21190], [21190]]
>>>
```

Comment: This gave me: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable. 

Edit: Sorry, this didn't work because some inner lists don't contain just one element.